# Change the dragged object when draggable begins

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to create some thing like a UI designer. So I have a 'toolbox' and a 'canvas'. When I mark the tool box items as draggable, I am able to drag them. But what I need is to drag a copy, so that I can drag multiple instances of a tool item to the canvas.

```
$('.tool-box-item').draggable({
    helper : 'clone',
    drag : function (event, ui){
        // jQuery does not allow object modification here
    },
});
```

This does not work as the cloning is applied only while dragging and as soon as the drag is complete, the original element moves. I tried overriding the drag property, but I am unable to modify the dragged element. Same was the case with start.

Note : I can not use the stop event as I want to create the copy when the drag starts and not after it. I was also able to create a copy by defining the canvas as droppable and making a copy there, But then again I want to create a copy when the drag starts.

I think I will need to create a custom drag function but was hoping if jQuery has any other alternative way.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z9rrL6po/3/), but I want to clone the element at the start and not after the drag.

EDIT : The destination is a 3rd party control. It has its own implementation for drop event (stacking and aligning). In case I clone it at the end I will have to modify their implementation.

Comment: Could you please explain, why should you clone element at start of dragging, but not at the end?

Comment: @YuriGor The destination is a 3rd party control. It has its own implementation for drop event (stacking and aligning). In case I clone it at the end I will have to modify their implementation.

Comment: I see.. Check for my answer below, I edited it according to this requierment, may be this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep "dragend" event, try to use original element for dragging, and clone it for place to your "toolbox".

```
var graggableConfig = {
  helper:"clone",
  stop: function(event, ui){
    var clon = $(this).clone();
    clon.attr("style","")
    .appendTo(".src")
    .draggable(graggableConfig);
    $(this).detach()
    .attr("style","")
    .appendTo(".dst")
    .draggable( "destroy" );
  }
}; 
$(".item").draggable(graggableConfig);
```

codepen [here](http://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/zoGrNQ)

Comment: Thanks man. This is close to what I needed. Set me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's `clone` (https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method to clone your draggable element once it is dropped. Would something like this meet your needs?

```
$( function() {
    makeDraggable($( "#draggable" ));
});

function makeDraggable(element) {
    $(element).attr('style', 'position:absolute').draggable({
        start: function() {
             makeDraggable($('#draggable').clone().attr('style', '').appendTo('body'));
        }
    });
}
```

Its a little rough but here is the jsbin: https://jsbin.com/tasodixoka/edit?html,output

Edit: I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z9rrL6po/6/

Comment: Sorry, but no. If you see the jsfiddle I posted it does something similar, I want to be able to clone it when the drag begins.

Comment: I might be getting a feeling that the draggable is not actually meant to do this, as we are not dragging the element in context.